# How to set a custom name instead of 'origin' as a git clone parameter?

Tags: git, clone

Is there a way to `git clone` with custom name instead of 'origin'? Usually when you do `git clone git@github.org:user/repo.git` you end up in having 'origin' in you git config, but I am inside remote script where issuing new command like `git remote add <name> <url>` costs me a lot. So I would like to squeeze all those things in one command.

Comment: Hi, deleting your question with the answer together is similarly bad than voting a question down/close without a reason. Do not do it, I think we want a good SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `clone.defaultRemoteName` config entry to that exact purpose, doc is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-clonedefaultRemoteName).